# How to check a record is a new record or already created one

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I'm unable to figure out on how to add "NOT(ISNEW)" and "AND" to my validation rule which is

```
OR( OR( Auditee__r.VanaHCM__User__c  <>  $User.Id ,  
        Auditee_2__r.VanaHCM__User__c  <> $User.Id), 
        ISCHANGED( Audit_Closure_Target_Date__c ) , 
        ISCHANGED( RCA__c ) , 
        ISCHANGED( Proposed_Correction_Corrective_Actions__c )
      )
```

as I need to fire this rule only in a record already created but this rule of mine fires even before i create a record and save it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a few things:

```
NOT(ISNEW())
```

Or:

```
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) <> Today()
```

Or:

```
CreatedDate <> NOW()
```

Comment: I actually want is to incorporate both NOT(ISNEW()) and AND in my formula such that it checks only the second time not during when the record is being created.

Comment: With NOT(ISNEW()) it will never execute the rule when the record is created... if you want to use it with something else then you'll need to do: ```AND( NOT(ISNEW()), XXXWhatever Else you need to valiedateXXX )``` If that's not it then can you clarify a little more... as I don't quite get what you want or need :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to my question which I figured at long last on my own. Thank u @Timothy

```
AND( NOT( ISNEW()), 
     ISCHANGED( Audit_Closure_Target_Date__c ) , 
     ISCHANGED( RCA__c ) , 
     ISCHANGED( Proposed_Correction_Corrective_Actions__c),
     OR( Auditee__r.VanaHCM__User__c <> $User.Id , 
         Auditee_2__r.VanaHCM__User__c <> $User.Id)
   )
```

Comment: See how much easier it is to read this code now that I've formatted it? It's also much easier to detect errors if you neaten it up like this.

Comment: Thank you casper but the formula which i created was very specific to my need and it worked out well and running good still even though i'm not with them. anyways thank you once again for replying to my question after 5 long years. Cheers thank u